# Как опустить текст под картинку

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
*{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html{
    background-color: #6a362b;
}
section{
    display: flex;
    
}
#shapka{
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #CEAD39;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F7F4A1;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}
#title{
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #2F3030;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.about{
    font-size: 30px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20%;
    text-align: right;
    color: #2F3030;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif; 
}
.games{
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 20%;
    color: #2F3030;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    text-align: left; 
}
img{
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 450px;
    object-fit: contain;
}
#first{
    max-width: 30%;
    max-height: 30%;
    margin: 25px;
    background-color: #74AE95;
    border: 2px solid #F7F4A1;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#text{
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2F3030;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;

}
#console{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2F3030;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;

}

#picture{
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    max-width: 10%;
    max-height: 15%;
}


#second{
    max-width: 30%;
    max-height: 30%;
    margin: 25px;
    background-color: #74AE95;
    border: 2px solid #F7F4A1;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
}
#third{
    max-width: 30%;
    max-height: 30%;
    margin: 25px;
    background-color: #74AE95;
    border: 2px solid #F7F4A1;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GAMEOK</title>
        <meta http-equiv=""Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSSGAMEOK.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
        <div id="shapka">
            <h1 id="title">Интернет Магазин "GAMEOK"</h1>
            <h1 href="https://www.google.com/" class="about">О нас</h1>
            <h1 class="games">Игры</h1>
        </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div id="first">
                <div id="picture"> <img src="ps4.jpg" alt="ps4"></div>
                <div id="text">
                    <h2 id="console">PlayStation 4</h2>
                    <br>
                    <span>Невероятные игры оживают на PS4 с жестким диском на 500 Гб или 1Тб.
                        <br>
                        Станьте одним из воинов-самураев, боритесь за выживание или почувствуйте 
                        <br>
                        себя могущественным божеством в самых известных шедеврах игровой индустрии, 
                        <br>
                        созданных в PlayStation Studios.
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="third">
                <div id="picture"> <img src="nintendo.jpg" alt="nintendo"> </div>
                <div id="text">
                    <h2 id="console">Nintendo Switch</h2>
                    <br>
                    <span>
                        Наслаждайтесь видеоиграми на домашней консоли даже без телевизора.
                        <br>
                        Nintendo Switch может подстраиваться под ситуацию,
                        <br>
                        так что вы можете играть в любимые игры,
                        <br>
                        даже несмотря на напряженный ритм жизни.
                        <br>
                        Наслаждайтесь играми всегда, везде и со всеми!
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="second">
                <div id="picture"> <img src="xbox.jpg" alt="xbox"></div>
                <div id="text">
                    <h2 id="console">XBOX ONE S</h2>
                    <br>
                    <span>
                        Играйте в крупнейшие блокбастеры, 
                        <br>
                        самые популярные и классические игры Xbox
                        <br>
                        из трех поколений самых любимых игр прошлого снова 
                        <br>
                        или испытайте эти эмоции впервые.
                        <br>
                        Получите доступ к более чем 100 высококачественным играм для консоли.
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете добавить элементам `img` тип отображения `block`:

`display: block;`

В примере я добавил элементу `#picture` тип отображения `flex` для центрирования картинок с помощью свойства `justify-content: center;`, указав ширину в 100% от ширины контейнера, убрав свойство `max-width`, `margin-left` и `max-height` для демонстрации правильной работы с произвольными размерами изображений.

```css
*{
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
html{
    background-color: #6a362b;
}
section{
    display: flex;
    
}
#shapka{
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #CEAD39;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #F7F4A1;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}
#title{
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #2F3030;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
.about{
    font-size: 30px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 20%;
    text-align: right;
    color: #2F3030;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif; 
}
.games{
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 20%;
    color: #2F3030;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    text-align: left; 
}
#picture img{
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 450px;
    object-fit: contain;
    display: block;
}
#first{
    max-width: 30%;
    max-height: 30%;
    margin: 25px;
    background-color: #74AE95;
    border: 2px solid #F7F4A1;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#text{
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2F3030;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;

}
#console{
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2F3030;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;

}

#picture{
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}


#second{
    max-width: 30%;
    max-height: 30%;
    margin: 25px;
    background-color: #74AE95;
    border: 2px solid #F7F4A1;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: right;
}
#third{
    max-width: 30%;
    max-height: 30%;
    margin: 25px;
    background-color: #74AE95;
    border: 2px solid #F7F4A1;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>GAMEOK</title>
        <meta http-equiv=""Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSSGAMEOK.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
        <div id="shapka">
            <h1 id="title">Интернет Магазин "GAMEOK"</h1>
            <h1 href="https://www.google.com/" class="about">О нас</h1>
            <h1 class="games">Игры</h1>
        </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            <div id="first">
                <div id="picture"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200/" alt="ps4"></div>
                <div id="text">
                    <h2 id="console">PlayStation 4</h2>
                    <br>
                    <span>Невероятные игры оживают на PS4 с жестким диском на 500 Гб или 1Тб.
                        <br>
                        Станьте одним из воинов-самураев, боритесь за выживание или почувствуйте 
                        <br>
                        себя могущественным божеством в самых известных шедеврах игровой индустрии, 
                        <br>
                        созданных в PlayStation Studios.
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="third">
                <div id="picture"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200/" alt="nintendo"> </div>
                <div id="text">
                    <h2 id="console">Nintendo Switch</h2>
                    <br>
                    <span>
                        Наслаждайтесь видеоиграми на домашней консоли даже без телевизора.
                        <br>
                        Nintendo Switch может подстраиваться под ситуацию,
                        <br>
                        так что вы можете играть в любимые игры,
                        <br>
                        даже несмотря на напряженный ритм жизни.
                        <br>
                        Наслаждайтесь играми всегда, везде и со всеми!
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="second">
                <div id="picture"> <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200/" alt="xbox"></div>
                <div id="text">
                    <h2 id="console">XBOX ONE S</h2>
                    <br>
                    <span>
                        Играйте в крупнейшие блокбастеры, 
                        <br>
                        самые популярные и классические игры Xbox
                        <br>
                        из трех поколений самых любимых игр прошлого снова 
                        <br>
                        или испытайте эти эмоции впервые.
                        <br>
                        Получите доступ к более чем 100 высококачественным играм для консоли.
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

покажу только первый обьект, остальные можно будет обработать потом так же:

```
<div id="first">
                <div id="picture">
                  <img src="ps4.jpg" alt="ps4">
                   <h2 id="console">PlayStation 4</h2>
                    <br>
                    <span>Невероятные игры оживают на PS4 с жестким диском на 500  Гб или 1Тб.
                        <br>
                        Станьте одним из воинов-самураев, боритесь за выживание или почувствуйте 
                        <br>
                        себя могущественным божеством в самых известных шедеврах игровой индустрии, 
                        <br>
                        созданных в PlayStation Studios.
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Здесь я удалила закрывающий тег `</div>` в котором был `<img>` и так же убрала открывающий `<div id="text">`.

Теперь надо будет только поправить CSS.

П.С. Думаю тебе будет лучше пользоваться не `<span>` в тексте а `<p>`, в таком случае он будет опускаться как только блок будет заканчиваться. Определи нужную тебе ширену только.

Comment: А почему тогда не добавили про то, что элементы не могут быть с одним иднификатором (id)? :)

Comment: Не посмотрела, извините!